# How to organize git in projects with overlapping dependencies?

Tags: git, dependencies, dependency-management, project-organization

Currently I am working on converting a monolithic SVN repository (all applications and libraries in a single repository) with mostly C++ code to a git repository. I would like to have organize it so that the libraries and applications are in their own repository.

I am, however, struggling to find a good way to handle internal (i.e. our own code) and overlapping dependencies. The problem exists because many libraries and applications depend on each other - often quite deep.

For instance, imagine the following (quite simple) project structure:

- app1 depends on lib1 lib2
- lib1 depends on lib2 lib3
- lib2 depends on lib3
- lib3 does not have dependencies

App1 could be a game, lib1 a graphics library, lib2 a math library and lib3 a utility library. Keep in mind that the libraries are also used in many other applications and are often updated.

Ideally I would want to have a situation where I get the following directory structure when I clone app1:

- app1

  - libs

    - lib1
    - lib2
    - lib3

and I get the following when I clone, for instance, lib2:

- lib2

  - libs

    - lib3

I have thought about using git subtree or submodules, whereby each project records its own dependencies. However, the project directory layout would then become something like this (for readability I removed the in-between libs directory):

- app1

  - lib1

    - lib2

      - lib3
    - lib3
  - lib2

    - lib3

As you can see lib3 and lib2 get placed in the project multiple times. Obviously that is not desirable.

I could solve this by writing a custom script for each application and library that clones all the relevant dependent repositories. When I do this however it becomes difficult to keep track of the exact state of the code at a specific commit.

Is there a good way to handle internal and overlapping dependencies with git? Or am I struggling because I am trying to achieve something that goes against the way of doing things in git?